# curl ignores interface parameter

Tags: networking, curl

My Ubuntu 12.04 laptop is connected to the Internet by WiFi and to the intranet by cable.

I would like to get the content of an intranet site via `curl` and have tried the following:

```
curl --interface eth0:1 intranet.bfs.admin.ch
```

the result is

```
curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host 'intranet.bfs.admin.ch'
```

When I disconnect the WiFi it works fine

According to the man page this should work. I also tried (to no avail)

```
curl --interface eth0:0 intranet.bfs.admin.ch
curl --interface eth0 intranet.bfs.admin.ch
curl --interface 10.147.128.132 intranet.bfs.admin.ch
```

I should mention that it is important that the WiFi stay the default interface.

Comment: Please paste you eth0 and wlan0 IP addresses

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe what you're seeing here is that when the wireless interface comes up, it gets its configuration via DHCP, which includes a DNS configuration that overwrites your intranet DNS configuration.

There's nothing about forcing `curl` to use a particular network interface that can help you with this. `curl` doesn't do its own DNS — that's a function of the underlying OS — and even if it did, simply forcing it to send packets to the WLAN DNS servers over the wired connection wouldn't do anything useful.

There are a bunch of ways to attack this problem.

The way I'd probably try first is to add the intranet's DNS servers to the WLAN DHCP configuration, setting them as higher priority than the Internet DNS servers you normally use. You might even drop the Internet DNS servers entirely, since the *intranet* DNS servers already likely know how to do Internet DNS lookups as well. You would effectively be using your local intranet DNS servers as caching DNS servers for Internet lookups, in addition to resolving local DNS names.

If you don't have control over the WLAN DHCP configuration, you can configure Ubuntu's DHCP configuration to use static DNS addresses; it will ignore what it gets from DHCP. Set it to use the intranet DNS servers instead.

Comment: With the caveat that since this is a laptop, hard coding the DNS addresses to the Intranet DNS servers will bite you when you take the laptop elsewhere.

Comment: @kurtm: Yes, that's why I suggested modifying the WLAN DHCP configuration first. It not only solves that problem, it means other WLAN clients get the fix at the same time, instead of having to modify them one by one.

Comment: Yes, and that is the much better fix.  I just wanted to make sure that the downside of going this way (which will be easier to change) is more explicit.